# Specified Gradle Installation (..) is not supported by this tooling API version (1.6, protocol version 4)

Tags: configuration, gradle, android-studio

I have just set up Android Studio 0.2.2 and updated my Android SDK to the latest version.
I have exported my Android project (android:minSdkVersion="8", android:targetSdkVersion="15") in Eclipse by 'Generate Gradle Build Files' without (visible) problems. And I can export/compile my app in Eclipse just fine, it also runs fine in the emulator.

However, in Android Studio, when trying to import my project, I am confronted with the above error message. "Gradle Home" is (IMO, correctly) displayed as "D:\Prog\Android-Studio\plugins\gradle".

Any idea how to make Android Studio feel more comfortable on my computer?..

Comment: I'm also getting this. However not quite the same because the import succeeds, but the above error happens during Make. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem where I can't import my project. There is at least one answer out there that may help; it requires the creation of a blank project in Android Studio and then copy files over from Eclipse. This ensures the creation by Android Studio of the necessary Gradle files, etc. Here's the link to the full answer: [Gradle build errors with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589515/gradle-build-errors-with-android-studio)

Look's like you should try to use the Gradle Wrapper rather than a local Gradle distribution. According to Gradle's website (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html):

> The wrapper is something you should check into version control. By distributing the wrapper with your project, anyone can work with it without needing to install Gradle beforehand. Even better, users of the build are guaranteed to use the version of Gradle that the build was designed to work with. Of course, this is also great for continuous integration servers (i.e. servers that regularly build your project) as it requires no configuration on the server.

You'll need to mimic the following structure in your project's directory:

```
simple/
  gradlew
  gradlew.bat
  gradle/wrapper/
    gradle-wrapper.jar
    gradle-wrapper.properties
```

At that point, go to Settings (Windows) Preferences (Mac), click "Gradle" on the left hand side, choose "Use Gradle wrapper (recommended)". If that option isn't available, try restarting Android Studio or closing and reimporting your project. Checking this option should ensure that you always build with the correct Gradle distribution.